# How to display dates with correct timezone on charts or tables using Ui Service?

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, timezone

When I'm trying to create table or chart on Ui Service using Date objects, it seems that dates are displayed in a timezone which is not the one that is currently configured in the script.

Here is a little example:

```
function doGet() {
  var dateObject = new Date ( "January 1, 2013 12:00:00" );
  Logger.log(dateObject);

  var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable()
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.DATE, 'DateColumn')
  .addRow([dateObject])
  .build();

  var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
  .setDataTable(dataTable)
  .build();

  var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();
  uiApp.add(tableChart);
  return uiApp;
}
```

When I launch the script as a `webApp`, I get this output:

```
DateColumn

1 janv. 2013 03:00:00
```

The hour is not correct but when I look into the log, it's fine:

```
[13-06-23 00:40:30:330 CEST] Tue Jan 01 12:00:00 GMT+01:00 2013
```

Is there a way to configure how the date will be displayed on the webapp?

Comment: if I refer to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder?hl=en#setOption(String,Object)), it should be something like that :   `var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart().setOption("DateFormat",{"timeZone":-2})`  but I tried without success... I probably missed something :-/

Comment: Convert the date and ColumnType to string?

Comment: Yes it can work for tables but for charts, if i want to use my dates as an X-axis like a timeline I can't do this trick.